# overlapping of button when size of window increases - javafx - fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an issue with buttons size. When I increase the size of my window,
The buttons overlap each other. I have tried many thnigs to avoid that, for example wrap each button in an anchorpane, without success.

Here is the fxml code used for the button "devis" for example:

```
<AnchorPane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="71.0" maxHeight="61.25" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="206.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="116.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="71.0">
  <children>
      <Button fx:id="devis" maxHeight="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectViewDevis" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="206.0" text="Devis" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The 2 images of my window before and after increasing

[Before increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heiQn.png)

[After increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Hu7.png)

Thanks for your help,

Aaron

Comment: Your code only has one button in it. Also, what do you actually want to happen when the user increases the window size?

Comment: My code has much more button. I wanted to make it short.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but how do you possibly think you can provide code that shows the buttons overlapping if you only provide code that has one button in it? How can anyone possibly tell you what you are doing wrong from that? Create a [MCVE]: you should be able to do this with (probably) two buttons and provide a complete, executable example that reproduces the problem (but, obviously, not your entire project). Explain what it is doing and how you actually want it to behave. Make sure you have read the basic tutorials and layout documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ['VBox'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.35451505016722407" layoutX="189.0" layoutY="167.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox layoutX="24.0" layoutY="14.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                           <children>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                        <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                        <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                        <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```